# vscode - Is there any api to get search results?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I try to search text in a file,I wonder if I could get the results searched by vscode.Is there some api that I can use?

I found some functions like TextSearchProvider in vscode proposed api,but this api is used to search text in whole workplace.I just want the result searched in one file.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOMFs.png)

For example,When I try to search Selection,I want the result of this search.

Comment: Do you want this in an extension that you are writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code from my extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform#review-details):

```js
function _findAndSelect(editor, findValue, restrictFind) {

    let foundSelections = [];

    // get all the matches in the document
    let fullText = editor.document.getText();
    let matches = [...fullText.matchAll(new RegExp(findValue, "gm"))];

    matches.forEach((match, index) => {
        let startPos = editor.document.positionAt(match.index);
        let endPos = editor.document.positionAt(match.index + match[0].length);
        foundSelections[index] = new vscode.Selection(startPos, endPos);
    });
    editor.selections = foundSelections; // this will remove all the original selections

}
```

Just get the text of the current document, do some string search like `matchAll` using your search term.  In the code above I wanted to select all those matches in the document - you may or may not be interested in that.

It looks like you want your search term to be the current selection:

```
// editor is the vscode.window.activeTextEditor

let selection = editor.selection;  
let selectedRange = new vscode.Range(selection.start, selection.end);
let selectedText = editor.document.getText(selectedRange);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!I think this is exactly what I want.